# Remove specific td borders on a table

Tags: html, css

I have a simple table, where I want to remove specific borders on `td` tag

Table replication:

```css
    #page {
        background: #ffffff;
        width: 878px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 10px;
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid #c4c7c7;
        padding: 20px 20px 25px 20px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
        font-family: Arial;
    }

    .br {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 0em;
    }

    .brmedium {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }

    .brlarge {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 2em;
    }

    .documentTitle {
        text-align: right;
    }

    .textCenter {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .numericText {
        font-size: 26px;
        font-family: Arial;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .square {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        border: 1px solid;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .yesNoSquare {
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        border: 1px solid;
        display: inline-block;
    }


    .yesNoSquare-space {
        padding-right: 20px;
    }

    .yesNoSquare-cross {
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid;
        display: inline-block;
    }

        .yesNoSquare-cross:after {
            position: absolute;
            top: -45px;
            bottom: 0;
            left: -1.5px;
            right: 0;
            content: "\2715"; 
            line-height: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #000000;
        }

    td {
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .tableTitle {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .tableText {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .remove-border {
        border: 0px solid #ffffff;
    }

    .commercialTable {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        /*vertical-align: top;*/
    }

    .commercialTable-space {
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .commercialTable tr, .commercialTable td {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        /*vertical-align: top;*/
    }

    .itemsTableHeader {
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .itemsTableTitle {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .itemTableSpace {
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .packagingDescriptionText {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .alignMiddle {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .footerMarkText {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .footerSignature {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="page">
    <h3 class="documentTitle">Test Test</h3>
    
    <table class="commercialTable">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="9" class="textCenter">
            <span class="tableTitle">test test test test</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2"></td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">test. g</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">ttest</span>
          </td>
          <td colspan="3" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">17. test, test test test, test, test test test</span>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">21</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test test</span>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">22</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test test (lb)</span>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">23</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test (test test, test test)</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">18. test test</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test test</span>
          </td>
          <td class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">19. test</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test test test</span>
          </td>
          <td class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">20. test test</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">(Kilos)</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">1</td>
          <td class="alignMiddle" rowspan="2">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">7318.15.50</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">2</td>
          <td class="alignMiddle" rowspan="2">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test-test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">8302.41.60</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">3</td>
          <td class="alignMiddle" rowspan="2">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">7318.22.00</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">4</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">7318.16.45</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">5</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">7318.16.45</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">6</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test test test bracket</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">8302.41.60</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">7</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">3925.90.00</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">8</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">9</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemsTableSpace" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">26. test test</span>
            <span class="packagingDescriptionText br">test test test(s), test test(es), test test test(s), test test(s)</span>
          </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">24. test test (lb)</span>
            {{test}}
          </td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">25. test test</span>
            {{test}}
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">27. test test (test test)</span>
            <div class="textCenter">
              <span class="yesNoSquare"></span>
              <span class="yesNoSquare-space itemsTableHeader"> YES</span>
              <span class="yesNoSquare"></span>
              <span class="itemsTableHeader"> NO</span>
            </div>

          </td>
          <td colspan="1" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">28. test test (test test)</span>
            <div class="textCenter">
              <div class="yesNoSquare-cross"></div>
              <span class=" yesNoSquare-space itemsTableHeader"> YES</span>
              <span class="yesNoSquare"></span>
              <span class="itemsTableHeader"> NO</span>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">29. test test (test)</span>
          </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">30. test</span>
          </td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">31. test test test</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" class="remove-border itemTableSpace">
          </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">32. test</span>
          </td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">33. test test</span>
            {{test}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p class="textCenter footerMarkText">test "X" in H.M. test test test test</p>
    <p class="footerSignature">34. test test:</p>
    <p class="footerSignature">X. test test - test test</p>
  </div>


</body>
```

So, I want to remove bottom and left borders (marked in red) on the picture bellow

[image]

I tried using a new class on that specific td as:

```
.removeBorders {
   border-bottom: 0px;
   border-left: 0px;
 }
```

But it does not work, it just no remove the borders,  how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems.

## Specificity

One aspect is that there is a [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) conflict.

The CSS from this rule:

```css
.commercialTable tr, .commercialTable td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    /*vertical-align: top;*/
}
```

is overriding this rule:

```css
.remove-border {
    border: 0px solid #ffffff;
}
```

because `.commercialTable td` has specificity of [0, 1, 1] whereas `.remove-border` has specificity of [0, 1, 0].

We can increase the specificity of the `.remove-border` a multitude of ways, such as `.remove-border[class]` which would be [0, 2, 0] and this would then beat `.commercialTable td`.

## `<tr>` border

Even when removing the border from the `<td>` element, the `<tr>` element still has a border, so that needs to be removed too. We can reuse the `remove-border` class here.

## Final code:

```css
    #page {
        background: #ffffff;
        width: 878px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 10px;
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid #c4c7c7;
        padding: 20px 20px 25px 20px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
        font-family: Arial;
    }

    .br {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 0em;
    }

    .brmedium {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }

    .brlarge {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 2em;
    }

    .documentTitle {
        text-align: right;
    }

    .textCenter {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .numericText {
        font-size: 26px;
        font-family: Arial;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .square {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        border: 1px solid;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .yesNoSquare {
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        border: 1px solid;
        display: inline-block;
    }


    .yesNoSquare-space {
        padding-right: 20px;
    }

    .yesNoSquare-cross {
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid;
        display: inline-block;
    }

        .yesNoSquare-cross:after {
            position: absolute;
            top: -45px;
            bottom: 0;
            left: -1.5px;
            right: 0;
            content: "\2715"; 
            line-height: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #000000;
        }

    td {
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .tableTitle {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .tableText {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .remove-border[class] {
        border: 0px solid #ffffff;
    }

    .commercialTable {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        /*vertical-align: top;*/
    }

    .commercialTable-space {
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .commercialTable tr, .commercialTable td {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        /*vertical-align: top;*/
    }

    .itemsTableHeader {
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .itemsTableTitle {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .itemTableSpace {
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .packagingDescriptionText {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .alignMiddle {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .footerMarkText {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .footerSignature {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="page">
    <h3 class="documentTitle">Test Test</h3>
    
    <table class="commercialTable">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="9" class="textCenter">
            <span class="tableTitle">test test test test</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2"></td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">test. g</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">ttest</span>
          </td>
          <td colspan="3" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">17. test, test test test, test, test test test</span>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">21</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test test</span>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">22</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test test (lb)</span>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">23</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test (test test, test test)</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">18. test test</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test test</span>
          </td>
          <td class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">19. test</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test test test</span>
          </td>
          <td class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">20. test test</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">(Kilos)</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">1</td>
          <td class="alignMiddle" rowspan="2">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">7318.15.50</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">2</td>
          <td class="alignMiddle" rowspan="2">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test-test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">8302.41.60</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">3</td>
          <td class="alignMiddle" rowspan="2">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">7318.22.00</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">4</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">7318.16.45</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">5</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">7318.16.45</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">6</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test test test bracket</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">8302.41.60</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">7</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">3925.90.00</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">8</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">9</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemsTableSpace" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">26. test test</span>
            <span class="packagingDescriptionText br">test test test(s), test test(es), test test test(s), test test(s)</span>
          </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">24. test test (lb)</span>
            {{test}}
          </td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">25. test test</span>
            {{test}}
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">27. test test (test test)</span>
            <div class="textCenter">
              <span class="yesNoSquare"></span>
              <span class="yesNoSquare-space itemsTableHeader"> YES</span>
              <span class="yesNoSquare"></span>
              <span class="itemsTableHeader"> NO</span>
            </div>

          </td>
          <td colspan="1" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">28. test test (test test)</span>
            <div class="textCenter">
              <div class="yesNoSquare-cross"></div>
              <span class=" yesNoSquare-space itemsTableHeader"> YES</span>
              <span class="yesNoSquare"></span>
              <span class="itemsTableHeader"> NO</span>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">29. test test (test)</span>
          </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">30. test</span>
          </td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">31. test test test</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="remove-border">
          <td colspan="5" class="remove-border itemTableSpace">
          </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">32. test</span>
          </td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">33. test test</span>
            {{test}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p class="textCenter footerMarkText">test "X" in H.M. test test test test</p>
    <p class="footerSignature">34. test test:</p>
    <p class="footerSignature">X. test test - test test</p>
  </div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass for the primary table styling called `.itemTableSpace.noBorder` and add `1px solid transparent` to the borders you don't want. Then apply it to the section HTML that you're targeting.

```css
#page {
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 878px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #c4c7c7;
  padding: 20px 20px 25px 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.br {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0em;
}

.brmedium {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.brlarge {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.documentTitle {
  text-align: right;
}

.textCenter {
  text-align: center;
}

.numericText {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 10px;
}

.square {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: auto;
}

.yesNoSquare {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}

.yesNoSquare-space {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.yesNoSquare-cross {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}

.yesNoSquare-cross:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -45px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -1.5px;
  right: 0;
  content: "\2715";
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
}

td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tableTitle {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.tableText {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.remove-border {
  border: 0px solid #ffffff;
}

.commercialTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  /*vertical-align: top;*/
}

.commercialTable-space {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.commercialTable tr,
.commercialTable td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  /*vertical-align: top;*/
}

.itemsTableHeader {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.itemsTableTitle {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.itemTableSpace {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.packagingDescriptionText {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.alignMiddle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.footerMarkText {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.footerSignature {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.itemTableSpace.noBorder {
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="page">
    <h3 class="documentTitle">Test Test</h3>

    <table class="commercialTable">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="9" class="textCenter">
            <span class="tableTitle">test test test test</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2"></td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">test. g</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">ttest</span>
          </td>
          <td colspan="3" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">17. test, test test test, test, test test test</span>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">21</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test test</span>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">22</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test test (lb)</span>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">23</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test (test test, test test)</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">18. test test</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test test</span>
          </td>
          <td class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">19. test</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test test test</span>
          </td>
          <td class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">20. test test</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">(Kilos)</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">1</td>
          <td class="alignMiddle" rowspan="2">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">7318.15.50</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">2</td>
          <td class="alignMiddle" rowspan="2">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test-test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">8302.41.60</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">3</td>
          <td class="alignMiddle" rowspan="2">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">7318.22.00</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">4</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">7318.16.45</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">5</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">7318.16.45</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">6</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test test test bracket</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">8302.41.60</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">7</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">3925.90.00</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">8</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">9</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemsTableSpace" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">26. test test</span>
            <span class="packagingDescriptionText br">test test test(s), test test(es), test test test(s), test test(s)</span>
          </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">24. test test (lb)</span> {{test}}
          </td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">25. test test</span> {{test}}
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">27. test test (test test)</span>
            <div class="textCenter">
              <span class="yesNoSquare"></span>
              <span class="yesNoSquare-space itemsTableHeader"> YES</span>
              <span class="yesNoSquare"></span>
              <span class="itemsTableHeader"> NO</span>
            </div>

          </td>
          <td colspan="1" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">28. test test (test test)</span>
            <div class="textCenter">
              <div class="yesNoSquare-cross"></div>
              <span class=" yesNoSquare-space itemsTableHeader"> YES</span>
              <span class="yesNoSquare"></span>
              <span class="itemsTableHeader"> NO</span>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">29. test test (test)</span>
          </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">30. test</span>
          </td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">31. test test test</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" class="itemTableSpace noBorder">
          </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">32. test</span>
          </td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">33. test test</span> {{test}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p class="textCenter footerMarkText">test "X" in H.M. test test test test</p>
    <p class="footerSignature">34. test test:</p>
    <p class="footerSignature">X. test test - test test</p>
  </div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not change the color of the borders? Make it transparent even.

```css
.remove-border {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent !important;
  border-left: 1px solid transparent !important;
}
```

If you care for the `!important` just use some selector specificity.

```css
#page {
        background: #ffffff;
        width: 878px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 10px;
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid #c4c7c7;
        padding: 20px 20px 25px 20px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
        font-family: Arial;
    }

    .br {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 0em;
    }

    .brmedium {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }

    .brlarge {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 2em;
    }

    .documentTitle {
        text-align: right;
    }

    .textCenter {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .numericText {
        font-size: 26px;
        font-family: Arial;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .square {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        border: 1px solid;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .yesNoSquare {
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        border: 1px solid;
        display: inline-block;
    }


    .yesNoSquare-space {
        padding-right: 20px;
    }

    .yesNoSquare-cross {
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid;
        display: inline-block;
    }

        .yesNoSquare-cross:after {
            position: absolute;
            top: -45px;
            bottom: 0;
            left: -1.5px;
            right: 0;
            content: "\2715"; 
            line-height: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #000000;
        }

    td {
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .tableTitle {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .tableText {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .remove-border {
        border-bottom: 1px solid transparent !important;
        border-left: 1px solid transparent !important;
    }

    .commercialTable {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        /*vertical-align: top;*/
    }

    .commercialTable-space {
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .commercialTable tr, .commercialTable td {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        /*vertical-align: top;*/
    }

    .itemsTableHeader {
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .itemsTableTitle {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .itemTableSpace {
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .packagingDescriptionText {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .alignMiddle {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .footerMarkText {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .footerSignature {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="page">
    <h3 class="documentTitle">Test Test</h3>
    
    <table class="commercialTable">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="9" class="textCenter">
            <span class="tableTitle">test test test test</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2"></td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">test. g</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">ttest</span>
          </td>
          <td colspan="3" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">17. test, test test test, test, test test test</span>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">21</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test test</span>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">22</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test test (lb)</span>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">23</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test (test test, test test)</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">18. test test</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test test</span>
          </td>
          <td class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">19. test</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">test test test</span>
          </td>
          <td class="textCenter">
            <span class="itemsTableHeader br">20. test test</span>
            <span class="itemsTableHeader">(Kilos)</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">1</td>
          <td class="alignMiddle" rowspan="2">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">7318.15.50</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">2</td>
          <td class="alignMiddle" rowspan="2">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test-test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">8302.41.60</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">3</td>
          <td class="alignMiddle" rowspan="2">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">7318.22.00</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">4</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">7318.16.45</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">5</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">7318.16.45</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">6</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test test test bracket</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">8302.41.60</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">7</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">test test test test</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace">3925.90.00</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">8</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemTableSpace" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="numericText textCenter alignMiddle">9</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="alignMiddle">
            <div class="square" />
          </td>
          <td class="itemsTableTitle itemsTableSpace" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">26. test test</span>
            <span class="packagingDescriptionText br">test test test(s), test test(es), test test test(s), test test(s)</span>
          </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">24. test test (lb)</span>
            {{test}}
          </td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">25. test test</span>
            {{test}}
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">27. test test (test test)</span>
            <div class="textCenter">
              <span class="yesNoSquare"></span>
              <span class="yesNoSquare-space itemsTableHeader"> YES</span>
              <span class="yesNoSquare"></span>
              <span class="itemsTableHeader"> NO</span>
            </div>

          </td>
          <td colspan="1" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">28. test test (test test)</span>
            <div class="textCenter">
              <div class="yesNoSquare-cross"></div>
              <span class=" yesNoSquare-space itemsTableHeader"> YES</span>
              <span class="yesNoSquare"></span>
              <span class="itemsTableHeader"> NO</span>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">29. test test (test)</span>
          </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">30. test</span>
          </td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">31. test test test</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" class="remove-border itemTableSpace">
          </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">32. test</span>
          </td>
          <td class="itemTableSpace">
            <span class="tableTitle br">33. test test</span>
            {{test}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p class="textCenter footerMarkText">test "X" in H.M. test test test test</p>
    <p class="footerSignature">34. test test:</p>
    <p class="footerSignature">X. test test - test test</p>
  </div>


</body>
```